# What is this thing called?!?! (bottom of screen popup)

Tags: html, javascript, jquery

I am looking for the name and some possible jquery libraries etc for the standard bottom of screen popup bar.

Its like a little bar that pops out on the bottom of the screen after X seconds or however really - generally slides up, about 50px or so high, and usually the length of the main container. used for some form of coupon advertisement or various promotion text etc.

What is the proper term for this item, and would there be any good references to best-use guidelines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "The Catfish". [Sitepoint wrote an article](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-catfish-part-1/) about doing it a long time ago but I'm sure it's still effective today.

Comment: Jquery UI can also be used for various overlays. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/